# How to go to a specific div in a different website page without # in the URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Throughout my website, I have a lot of anchor tags that send the user to a specific div on another webpage (like href="books.php#first" for example). I want to remove the # from the URL. I have tried doing with .htaccess but based on what I have read, rewriting the # was impossible. I would like to ask what another method I could use to remove the # from my URL. I have found out that something similar is possible with using jQuery or JavaScript for scrolling to specific points in a single webpage, however, I could not find out an answer on how to do it about a different page.

Comment: You could put the bookmark in sessionStorage instead, but you'd need to write the logic yourself to scroll the page down to the relevant element when the page loads.

Comment: Why would you want this in the first place? This is a simple mechanism _intended_ for exactly such purposes. By removing it from the URL, you would f.e. rob users of the possibility to bookmark or share such links to specific sections.

Comment: Because what I am doing is having a single id named #center on each page and whenever a person clicks something on the navigation I want them to be directed to that part of the webpage. I don't have multiple ids that I redirect to in a single webpage. The example I gave had nothing to do with my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use localStorage or sessionStorage like so: 
In the first page where the anchor tag is located

```
<a href="page.html" onclick="localStorage.setItem('anchor' , 'mydiv')"> Link</a>
```

in the target page

```
   <script>
    $(function () {
        // on document load 

        // if localStorage["anchor"] is set to a value 
        let target = localStorage.getItem("anchor");
        if (target) {

            // scroll to target 
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(target).offset().top }, 'slow');

            // clear localStorage 
            localStorage.removeItem("anchor");
        }
    });
</script>
```